# Android NDK: override dynamic linking for native libraries?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, libpng, android-security

I have an application that uses some native libraries through .SO files.

I'm in a situation where I can't upload a new version of the app to Google play because those native libraries link to old versions of OpenSSL and LibPNG which have security vulnerabilities as described here: https://android-developers.blogspot.com.eg/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html

My question is: is there any way to include the .SO files in a new project, along with the new versions of OpenSSL and LibPNG and override the linking to the old versions of OpenSSL and LibPNG?

Knowing that I can't rebuild the .SO files because I don't have the source files.

Is there any workaround for solving this?

Comment: *is there any way to include the .SO* obviously as long as your library is not using dynamic openssl/libpng library then you can't

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain more?

Comment: More then **you can't** ?... think about [statically compiled library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) as the part of the program itself ... and you didn't wrote if you are using OpenSSL and LibPNG as dynamic or static library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lost access to the source code of your library, but have the `.o` files (or the `.a` archive), you can choose a different version of dependencies.

If you use OpenSSL and libPNG as dynamic libraries, your life is easier. If you have them statically linked into your `.so` file, you need some [*advanced ELF manipulation techniques*](http://comp.os.linux.development.apps.narkive.com/Nf45vIVc/relink-a-dynamically-linke-executable-to-make-some-of-the-libraries-static) which may help if you are lucky and determined.

All this can only work if the interfaces that you use to these libraries remain untouched.